# forEachFeatureAtPixel does not work properly

Tags: openlayers-3

I have the following code,
basically I have two layers one osm laryer, one vector layers, first I add two feature nodes with id 1 and id 2  into the vector layer by single click at two random locations on the map using ol.interaction.draw, then switch to interaction drag by select 'Drag Point' (top left corner), the idea is when drag either one of the two nodes over the other node, the node being dragged shall turn into green node, I can do this by dragging node id 1 to to node id 2 easily, but when i try to drag node id 2 to node id 1, it  demands much higher accuracy than vice versa. The only difference between two nodes is node id 1 is created before node id 2.
The problem I see here is in forEachFeatureAtPixel, it rarely detects(or the call back rarely return node id 1) feature node id 1 when dragging node id 2 over node id 1. 
I have spent quite a while on this issue. Still cannot figure out why. Really appreciated any help. 
Thanks

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Draw and Modify Features</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form class="form-inline">
        <select id="type">
        <option value="DrawPoint">Draw Point</option>
        <option value="DragPoint">Drag Point</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
   
   <script>
   var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
 });

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
   center: [-11000000, 4600000],
   zoom: 4
  })
 });
var circle_style = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
   radius: 5,
   fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 2)'
   })
  })
 });
var overlap_style = new ol.style.Style({
     image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 8,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
       color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 2)'
      })
     })
    });
var features = new ol.Collection();
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
   features: features
  }),
  style: circle_style
 });
featureOverlay.setMap(map);

window.app = {};
var app = window.app;

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {ol.interaction.Pointer}
 */
app.Drag = function () {

 ol.interaction.Pointer.call(this, {
  handleDownEvent: app.Drag.prototype.handleDownEvent,
  handleDragEvent: app.Drag.prototype.handleDragEvent,
  handleMoveEvent: app.Drag.prototype.handleMoveEvent,
  handleUpEvent: app.Drag.prototype.handleUpEvent
 });


 this.coordinate12_ = null;

 
 this.cursor_ = 'pointer';

 
 this.feature_ = null;

 
 this.previousCursor_ = undefined;

};
ol.inherits(app.Drag, ol.interaction.Pointer);
app.Drag.prototype.handleDownEvent = function (evt) {
 var map = evt.map;
 
 var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
   function (feature, layer) {
   return feature;
  });

 if (feature) {
  console.log("down: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
  this.coordinate12_ = evt.coordinate;
  this.feature_ = feature;
 }

 return !!feature;
};

app.Drag.prototype.handleDragEvent = function (evt) {

 var map = evt.map;
 fs = featureOverlay.getSource().getFeatures();
 
 var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
   function (feature, layer) {
   return feature;
  });
 
 if (!(feature === undefined)) {
  console.log("drag: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
  // console.log("this:" + this.feature_.getId()+ " o: " +  feature.getId());
  if (this.feature_.getProperties()['id'] != feature.getProperties()['id']) {
   console.log("green: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
   this.feature_.setStyle(overlap_style);
  } else {
   this.feature_.setStyle(circle_style);
  }
 }

 var deltaX = evt.coordinate[0] - this.coordinate12_[0];
 var deltaY = evt.coordinate[1] - this.coordinate12_[1];

 var geometry = /** @type {ol.geom.SimpleGeometry} */
  (this.feature_.getGeometry());
 geometry.translate(deltaX, deltaY);

 this.coordinate12_[0] = evt.coordinate[0];
 this.coordinate12_[1] = evt.coordinate[1];
};
app.Drag.prototype.handleMoveEvent = function (evt) {
 if (this.cursor_) {
  var map = evt.map;
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function (feature, layer) {
    if (this.feature_ != null) 
    {
     console.log("move forEachFeatureAtPixel: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
    }
    return feature;
   });
  var element = evt.map.getTargetElement();
  if (feature) {
      if (this.feature_ != null) 
    {
     console.log("move forEachFeatureAtPixel: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
    }
   if (element.style.cursor != this.cursor_) {
    this.previousCursor_ = element.style.cursor;
    element.style.cursor = this.cursor_;
   }
  } else if (this.previousCursor_ !== undefined) {
   element.style.cursor = this.previousCursor_;
   this.previousCursor_ = undefined;
  }
 }
};

/**
 * @param {ol.MapBrowserEvent} evt Map browser event.
 * @return {boolean} `false` to stop the drag sequence.
 */
app.Drag.prototype.handleUpEvent = function (evt) {
 this.coordinate12_ = null;
 this.feature_ = null;
 return false;
};
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  features: features,
  type: ('Point')
 });
var drag = new app.Drag();
var id_count = 0;
draw.on('drawend', function(e) {
  e.feature.setProperties({
    'id': ++id_count
  })
  console.log(e.feature, e.feature.getProperties());
});
map.addInteraction(draw);

var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
typeSelect.value = 'DrawPoint';
typeSelect.onchange = function () {
 if (typeSelect.value == 'DrawPoint')
 {
  map.removeInteraction(drag);
  map.addInteraction(draw);
 }else
 {
  map.removeInteraction(draw);
  map.addInteraction(drag);
 }
};
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent the feature(be it 1st or 2nd) which is being moved to get returned from `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` method.
See the below working code snippet.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Draw and Modify Features</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form class="form-inline">
        <select id="type">
        <option value="DrawPoint">Draw Point</option>
        <option value="DragPoint">Drag Point</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
   
   <script>
    var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
 });

 var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
   center: [-11000000, 4600000],
   zoom: 4
  })
 });
 var circle_style = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
   radius: 5,
   fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 2)'
   })
  })
 });
 
 var overlap_style = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
   radius: 8,
   fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 2)'
   })
  })
 });
 var features = new ol.Collection();
 var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
   features: features
  }),
  style: circle_style
 });
 featureOverlay.setMap(map);

 window.app = {};
 var app = window.app;

 /**
  * @constructor
  * @extends {ol.interaction.Pointer}
  */
 var dragFeature;
 app.Drag = function () {

  ol.interaction.Pointer.call(this, {
   handleDownEvent: app.Drag.prototype.handleDownEvent,
   handleDragEvent: app.Drag.prototype.handleDragEvent,
   handleMoveEvent: app.Drag.prototype.handleMoveEvent,
   handleUpEvent: app.Drag.prototype.handleUpEvent
  });


  this.coordinate12_ = null;
  this.cursor_ = 'pointer';
  this.previousCursor_ = undefined;

 };
 ol.inherits(app.Drag, ol.interaction.Pointer);
 app.Drag.prototype.handleDownEvent = function (evt) {
  var map = evt.map;
  
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function (feature, layer) {
    return feature;
   });

  if (feature) {
   //console.log("down: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
   this.coordinate12_ = evt.coordinate;
   //this.feature_ = feature;
   dragFeature = feature;
  }

  return !!feature;
 };

 app.Drag.prototype.handleDragEvent = function (evt) {

  var map = evt.map;
  fs = featureOverlay.getSource().getFeatures();
  
  // Filter the feature 
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function (feature, layer) {
    if ( feature.getProperties()['id'] != dragFeature.getProperties()['id'] ) {
     return feature;
    }
   });
  
  if (!(feature === undefined)) {
   console.log("------------------- drag: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
   // console.log("this:" + this.feature_.getId()+ " o: " +  feature.getId());
   if (dragFeature.getProperties()['id'] != feature.getProperties()['id']) {
    console.log("green: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
    dragFeature.setStyle(overlap_style);
   }
  }
  else {
    dragFeature.setStyle(circle_style);
   }

  var deltaX = evt.coordinate[0] - this.coordinate12_[0];
  var deltaY = evt.coordinate[1] - this.coordinate12_[1];

  var geometry = /** @type {ol.geom.SimpleGeometry} */
   (dragFeature.getGeometry());
  geometry.translate(deltaX, deltaY);

  this.coordinate12_[0] = evt.coordinate[0];
  this.coordinate12_[1] = evt.coordinate[1];
 };
 app.Drag.prototype.handleMoveEvent = function (evt) {
  if (this.cursor_) {
   var map = evt.map;
   var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
     function (feature, layer) {
     if (dragFeature != null) 
     {
      //console.log("move forEachFeatureAtPixel: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
     }
     return feature;
    });
   var element = evt.map.getTargetElement();
   if (feature) {
    if (dragFeature != null) 
     {
      //console.log("move forEachFeatureAtPixel: node_id: " + feature.getProperties()['id']);
     }
    if (element.style.cursor != this.cursor_) {
     this.previousCursor_ = element.style.cursor;
     element.style.cursor = this.cursor_;
    }
   } else if (this.previousCursor_ !== undefined) {
    element.style.cursor = this.previousCursor_;
    this.previousCursor_ = undefined;
   }
  }
 };

 /**
  * @param {ol.MapBrowserEvent} evt Map browser event.
  * @return {boolean} `false` to stop the drag sequence.
  */
 app.Drag.prototype.handleUpEvent = function (evt) {
  this.coordinate12_ = null;
  //this.feature_ = null;
  dragFeature = null;
  return false;
 };
 var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
   features: features,
   type: ('Point')
  });
 var drag = new app.Drag();
 var id_count = 0;
 draw.on('drawend', function(e) {
   e.feature.setProperties({
  'id': ++id_count
   })
   //console.log(e.feature, e.feature.getProperties());
 });
 map.addInteraction(draw);

 var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
 typeSelect.value = 'DrawPoint';
 typeSelect.onchange = function () {
  if (typeSelect.value == 'DrawPoint')
  {
   map.removeInteraction(drag);
   map.addInteraction(draw);
  }else
  {
   map.removeInteraction(draw);
   map.addInteraction(drag);
  }
 };
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sumanth, thanks for your quick response, it's working now, but I still have one more question, what the difference it makes when you move function object variable this._feature to global variable dragFeature? Many thanks for your help

Comment: **this** object in `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` callback function is window object not **Drag** object. `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` is working on window object.